# Android No Animation When Transitioning From a Portrait Activity to a Landscape Activity

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition

I have Activity A which is set to run in portrait orientation (android:screenOrientation="portrait" set on this activity in the manifest). This activity opens to Activity B on a button click. Activity B is set to run in landscape orientation (android:screenOrientation="landscape" set on this activity in the manifest). Regardless of what I set in my overridePendingTransition method, there is never an animation. It's always a hard cut. Is there a way to force some sort of animation when transitioning from Activity A to Activity B?

Also, I get the same issue when transitioning back from Activity B to Activity A.

Edit (from Praveen):

Even i have decalred the `configChanges="orientation"` in the Manifest. Still i am facing this Problem?? Any Idea on this???

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you get any update on this?? i am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I have not come across a solution for this as of yet. I'm still dealing with the hard cut. My only other solution would be to have these be views instead of activities and do the animation on the views.

Comment: I have the same problem. If I use setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); in activity.onCreate instead of setting landscape in manifest, then it animates on startup, but still not on exit, and not on pause/resume (from home screen or other activity).

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to override activity's onConfigurationChange method.
perhaps this will help you.

for example

@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

```
    updateGui();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this after you run startActivity() :

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

Comment: I'm doing this already. As I said in my original question, regardless of what animations I give this method, there is never an animation. It's always a hard transition.

Comment: Check android settings -- you could have turn off the animation option.